# Having trouble understanding how npm soap package works

Tags: api, soap, npm

I'm using the npm soap package to connect to a SOAP API and call methods, and I'm not grasping how this is supposed to work.

For instance, in the API documentation, it gives this as an example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://xxx">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:setSessionParameters>
            <viewSettings>
                <forceLogoutSession>yes</forceLogoutSession>
                <rollingPeriod>Minutes30</rollingPeriod>
                <shiftStart>21600000</shiftStart>
                <statisticsRange>CurrentDay</statisticsRange>
                <timeZone>-28800000</timeZone>
                <idleTimeOut>1800</idleTimeOut>
            </viewSettings>
        </ser:setSessionParameters>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And if I use a REST tool to send this content to the API endpoint, it works as expected.

In my code, if I invoke this method call:

```
var x = client.describe();
console.log(x.WsSupervisorService.WsSupervisorPort.setSessionParameters);
```

I get this response:

```
{
  input: {
    viewSettings: {
      appType: 'xs:string',
      forceLogoutSession: 'xs:boolean',
      rollingPeriod: 'rollingPeriod|xs:string|Minutes5,Minutes10,Minutes15,Minutes30,Hour1,Hours2,Hours3,Today',
      shiftStart: 'xs:int',
      statisticsRange: 'statisticsRange|xs:string|RollingHour,CurrentDay,CurrentWeek,CurrentMonth,Lifetime,CurrentShift',
      timeZone: 'xs:int',
      targetNSAlias: 'tns',
      targetNamespace: 'http://xxx'
    },
    targetNSAlias: 'tns',
    targetNamespace: 'http://xxx'
  },
  output: {
    targetNSAlias: 'tns',
    targetNamespace: 'http://xxx'
  }
}
```

But this fails:

```
client.setSessionParameters({
  input: {
    viewSettings: {
      forceLogoutSession: true,
      rollingPeriod: 'Minutes30',
      shiftStart: 216000000,
      statisticsRange: 'CurrentDay',
      timeZone: -288000000,
      idleTimeOut: 1800
    }
  }
});
```

...yielding this error:

> { [Error: env:Client: Endpoint {http://xxx/}WsSupervisorPort does not contain operation meta data for: setSessionParameters] stack: [Getter] }

I'm at a loss here. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
client.setSessionParameters({
    viewSettings: {
      forceLogoutSession: true,
      rollingPeriod: 'Minutes30',
      shiftStart: 216000000,
      statisticsRange: 'CurrentDay',
      timeZone: -288000000,
      idleTimeOut: 1800
  }
});
```